# Ruby - Need the ability to add a function to button

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am trying to add the function where the user is able to 'Join' a activity once the button is clicked. However i'm not sure how to add the function in a method.
I currently have the code below in my html.erb file

```
<div class="actions">
  <%= submit_tag 'Join', name: 'join_event', class: "btn btn-sm btn-success " %>
</div>
```

and the code I am not sure how to add it to the controller I was thinking of adding a method called join_event but not sure of the syntax to add where it adds a 'activity' to a user.

Comment: You are going to need a `<%= form_tag ... %>` around that `submit_tag`. Look that up to get started on adding a form that POSTs to a controller "action".

Answer (score 0):

You can use button_to view helper in your erb file

```
 <%= button_to "Join Activity", controller: "users", action: "join", data: {"any data you would like to send"}, remote: true %>
```

This will submit a form (POST request) in the background (thanks to *'remote'* option) to users controllers join method with data object.

You can then use that data in Users controller join method to update the user or the activity according to your business logic.

If instead you want to submit to a different controller just change the options to button_to helper.

Dont forget to add the routes to your routes file such as

```
post 'users/join', to: 'users#join'
```